# Find the derivative of the Caputo fractional derivative

Tags: fractional-calculus

I tried:

```
 D[CaputoD[y[t], {t, 1/2}], t](* ? *)
 (* 0 *)
```

And:

```
  Integrate[CaputoD[y[t], {t, 1/2}], t]
  (* 0 *)
```

I tried with ChatGPT 3.5 and give me **zero** to.
[image]

This is a correct answer?

By the way with the **Riemann-Liouville** fractional derivative:

```
 D[FractionalD[y[t], {t, 1/2}], t](*Looks Ok*)
 (*-(y[t]/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] t^(3/2))) + Derivative[1][y][t]/(Sqrt[\[Pi]] Sqrt[t]) *)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the `CaputoD[]` definition has a bug. In general case we have

```
f = CaputoD[y[t], {t, q}];

D[f, t]

(*Out[]=
Piecewise[{{-((q*t^(-1 - q)*y[t])/Gamma[1 - q]), q <= 0}}, 0] + Piecewise[{{1/(t^q*Gamma[1 - q]), q <= 0}}, 0]*Derivative[1][y][t]*)
```

Therefore in particular case we have

```
%/. {y[t] -> t^3, q -> 1/2}

Out[]= 0
```

From the other side we can compute first

```
f1 = CaputoD[t^3, {t, 1/2}]

Out[]=
(16*t^(5/2))/(5*Sqrt[Pi])
```

Then we compute derivative

```
D[f1, t]

Out[]=
(8*t^(3/2))/Sqrt[Pi]
```

So, bug is in general definition.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure I was right .Thanks +1

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk You are welcome!